# phonegap ios CFBundleVersion not working

Tags: cordova

this is my config:

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "myapp.id"
        version   = "1.1.0"
    ios-CFBundleVersion = "111111111"
windows-packageVersion = "1.1.0">
```

i tried 1.1.0, 110, 11111111, but it always gets it as "version build 100" and i'm unable to update my app. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can add CFBundleVersion as`<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleVersion"><string>101</string></gap:config-file>`